# AWS Rename Glue Job Output

Tags: python, scala, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

From what I've read online, there's no possibility to name the output file right afterwards it's Glue job, but I've read that there's possibility to re-name the file after the job. But what I've came across is the fact of renaming a single output file, but i would like to do it for every file in the bucket (I'll be running glue job once after some period of time). I have no idea how to implement it though. I want my output files to be named same as the input files. Is anyone in possession of snippet of such code? It can be any type of language from the ones available in AWS Glue Jobs

Comment: You can use S3's mv operation to rename the files. However it is a very costly operation. What is the purpose of renaming the file?

Comment: That would make up for even more of a workaround - i would have to create lambda, that fetches data from s3 tmp names job bucket, and then changes names in the other bucket. it IS indeed costly, that's why I'm asking about the renaming function in the same Job - I've seen solutions do it, but never got a code snippet

Comment: The file names are generated by spark, there are ways to provide a custom naming convention. However, we don't have much control on spark running in glue-etl. What is main purpose of renaming the file?